# How to get IOS app store country in Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

Good time of the day

I am using Unity IAP version 2.2.2

I wanted to get IOS app store's country.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproduct/1506145-pricelocale?language=objc) I see in Apple docs that product contains priceLocale to get locale. But in unity iap, product doesn't contains this field in product's information.

```
com.example.puzzles.annual: {"introductoryPrice":"0","introductoryPriceLocale":"USD","introductoryPriceNumberOfPeriods":"1","numberOfUnits":"1","unit":"1"}
```

How can I get iOS app store's country?
P.S. IP location or getting country from isoCurrencyCode are not an option for me

Comment: Did you manage to get an answer for this?

Comment: Hi, There is no info coming from Unity IAP. So, managed to write ios native plugin to get app store country when IAP is initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was looking at similar solutions too.
Did you end up somehow using the [priceLocale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproduct/1506145-pricelocale?language=objc) of the items or simply the [countryCode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorefront/3182435-countrycode?language=objc) of the [SKStorefront](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorefront?language=objc)? The latter seems to only be available for iOS 13+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those who wants to get App store country on IOS.

Create a c# class MyNativeBindings.cs

```
public class MyNativeBindings
{
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    public static extern void LoadLocationInfo(string productId);
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    public static extern string GetLocationCode();
}
```

Create ios native objective-c class MyNativeBindings.mm and move to **Asset/Plugins/ios** folder

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
#include <string>

@class ProductRequestResponseDelegate;
@interface ProductRequestResponseDelegate : NSObject  <SKProductsRequestDelegate>;
@property (nonatomic) std::function<void(const std::string  &type, const std::string &country_code)> callback;

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response;

@end

static ProductRequestResponseDelegate * g_delegate = nil;

extern "C" {

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // Helper method to create C string copy
    char* MakeStringCopy (NSString* nsstring)
    {
        if (nsstring == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        // convert from NSString to char with utf8 encoding
        const char* string = [nsstring cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if (string == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }

        // create char copy with malloc and strcpy
        char* res = (char*)malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
        strcpy(res, string);
        return res;
    }

    void LoadLocationInfo(const char* productId) {
        g_delegate = [[ProductRequestResponseDelegate alloc] init];
        g_delegate.callback = [](const std::string & type, const std::string & code) {
//            NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [userDefaults registerDefaults:@{@"loc_type": [NSString stringWithUTF8String:type.c_str()]}];
            [userDefaults registerDefaults:@{@"loc_code": [NSString stringWithUTF8String:code.c_str()]}];
            NSLog(@"%@",[userDefaults objectForKey:@"loc_type"]);
            NSLog(@"%@",[userDefaults objectForKey:@"loc_code"]);
        };
        
        auto set = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects: [NSString stringWithUTF8String: productId], nil];
        
        auto request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: set];
        request.delegate = g_delegate;
        [request start];
    }

    char* GetLocationType()
    {
        NSString *s = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"loc_type"];
        return MakeStringCopy(s);
    }

    char* GetLocationCode()
    {
        NSString *s = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"loc_code"];
        return MakeStringCopy(s);
    }
}



@implementation ProductRequestResponseDelegate

-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (!self.callback)
            return;
        
        auto products = [response products];
        
        if ([products count] == 0)
        {
            self.callback("", "");
            return;
        }
        
        auto product = [products firstObject];
        if (![product respondsToSelector: @selector(priceLocale)])
        {
            self.callback("", "");
            return;
        }
        
        auto locale = [product priceLocale];
        if ([locale respondsToSelector: @selector(countryCode)])
            self.callback("code", [[locale countryCode] UTF8String]);
        else
            self.callback("identifier", [[locale localeIdentifier] UTF8String]);
    });
}



@end
```

1. You should call **MyNativeBindings.LoadLocationInfo(productID)** when
   IAP initialized.
2. Then call **MyNativeBindings.GetLocationCode()** to get store country short code.